# MongoDB Array Query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Пытаюсь сделать запрос для перебора массива JSON объектов с целью найти те, в которых либо isWinner - true, либо isFixLot - true. Одно из условий является то, что массив может быть вообще пустой. Можете помочь с созданием запроса? Последний раз когда пробовал получилось что-то вроде этого

```
    where = {  "bids": { $nin: [undefined, "", []] }, 
       "bids": { $in: [{'isWinner': true}, {'isFixLot': true}] }
    }
```

Но в итоге получаю ошибку

```
(node:70585) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'bids' of undefined
```

Пример входных данных

```
 { _id: 5f0c4daf77db5d2fb4cddbf9,
  is:
   { updated: 2020-07-13T12:03:59.158Z,
     created: 2020-10-07T10:03:59.158Z,
     enabled: true },
  isPaymentSet: true,
  approved: false,
  emails: [ '' ],
  password:
   'W',
  surname: 'usr',
  name: 'test',
  __v: 1,
  logins:
   [],
  settings: [],
  bids:
   [ { _id: 123,
       currencyId: 'RUB',
       userPaymentId: 123,
       count: 1,
       value: 1000,
       userId: 123,
       lotId: 123,
       is: [Object],
       isWinner: true,
       isAnonymous: false,
       isFixedLot: true,
       __v: 0 } ] }
```

Comment: Переведите вопрос на русский язык

Comment: Можно 2-3 экземпляра этих JSON-объектов? И ожидаемый вывод? Чтобы можно было у себя воспроизводить для повышения точности ответа, например.

Comment: Навскидку напрашивается что-то вроде такого: `{$or : [{'bids.isWinner' : true}, {'bids.isFixLot' : true}]}`. Хотя без знания модели наверняка не скажешь.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, указал пример

Comment: @Yaant данный метод не совсем подходит для массива bids

Comment: А поконкретнее, чем именно не подходит?

Comment: @Yaant все отлично, я просто поторопился с написанием запроса. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

@Yaant дал корректный ответ на вопрос

```
{$or : [{'bids.isWinner' : true}, {'bids.isFixLot' : true}]}
```

В данном случае даже если массив пустой не возникает проблем